# htaccess redirect to subfolder, if URL contains string

Tags: php, .htaccess

I feel really sorry, cause I feel like this is a simple question and it was answered few times, but I can't solve my problem ;(

I have a folder structure like this:

```
restaurant (folder)

.htaccess

index.php

anotherfile.php

few_more_files.php
```

---

htaccess file in root directory contains this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(test\.pdf|\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I need a way to implement logic:

if URL contains `mydomain.com/restaurant/any_other_strings_here`, I need to redirect to `/restaurant/index.php` file

What should I do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle domain and url separatetly:

```
# Only redirect if domain = dmydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$
# Redirect only if url contains restaurant/any_other_strings_here
# L = last = End htaccess evaluation after this rule
# R=301 = Redirect with status 301
RewriteRule restaurant/any_other_strings_here$ /restaurant/index.php [L,R=301]
```

Probably "any_other_string" refers to something wildcardish, so this might be better for you:

```
RewriteRule restaurant/(.*)$ /restaurant/index.php  [L,R=301]
```